# Facing a problem while integrating TFLITE custom model with flutter using the tflite plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

I built a custom model using Keras and converted it to TFLITE model. The input shape to the CNN model is 60*60*3 so as the datatype is int, the required buffer would be 60*60*3*4=43200. Now while integrating the model with **Flutter** using the function-

```
    recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
          path: widget.imagePath,
          imageMean: 127.5,
          imageStd: 127.5,
          numResults: 2,
          threshold: 0.1,
          asynch: true);
      print(recognitions);
    }
```

I received this error-

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(21412): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 21600 bytes and a Java Buffer with 43200 bytes.
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:332)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDataIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.setTo(Tensor.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:311)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:272)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.runTflite(TflitePlugin.java:452)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:419)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:393)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    ... 4 more
```

Any Suggestions on how I could solve this error?